# Notepad++ delete all text in a file but not strings that begin with 8D

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am racking my brains trying to figure out how to solve this problem I have. Here are some sample records from my text file:

```
active users 8D1DF3
active users by test 8D04R0
active users by maker 8DZZ99
active users by report class 8D2CV6
```

I am trying to find a way to a way using regular expressions in Notepad++ to remove all of the text except for the strings that start with 8D, the result would be this:

```
8D1DF3
8D04R0
8DZZ99
8D2CV6
```

In my research I have only found the possibility to remove lines based on strings being found not the ability to remove all text from lines other than the strings I want to keep.
Any clues as to how I can achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the regex below:

```
(?<!\S)(?!8D)\S+|\h+
```

and replace with nothing.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/qAfDPF/1)

Breakdown:

- `(?<!\S)` Shouldn't be preceded by a non-whitespace character (it shouldn't start match from the middle)
- `(?!8D)` A sub-string shouldn't start with `8D`
- `\S+` Match the rest
- `|\h+` Or match horizontal whitespaces

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, it does exactly what I wanted, thank you! I will need to study the regex to get an understanding of exactly what it did to achieve what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

The Regex you want could be this, then replace with '`\1`':

```
.*(8D.{4})
```

It actually matches everything, but creates a Group with `'8D'` (and four more characters), you can use for `replace`.